# Stacked bar ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, pivot, stacked-chart

I have a table like this:
`dput` of data

```
dput(data)
structure(list(status = c("Recovered", "Dead", "On-Treatment"
), northern_countries = c(24130778L, 955048L, 15634207L), Southern_countries = c(9157967L, 
308243L, 726474L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L
))

        status northern_countries Southern_countries
1    Recovered           24130778            9157967
2         Dead             955048             308243
3 On-Treatment           15634207             726474
```

I would like to create a stacked bar plot that shows the percentage of Dead, Recovered and On treatments which 2 bars are northern_countries and southern_countries.

I've been searching around but couldn't find the answer :( Also I've just started with R so please if could you elucidate things in details I'd be much appreciated.

Thanks so much xoxo

Comment: Though you have not included the it is clear that you need to pivot_longer your data (last 2 columns) before making a chart

Comment: `data %>% pivot_longer(cols = c(northern_countries, Southern_countries), 
                      names_to= "countries", values_to = "value") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=status, y=value)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill= countries), position = "dodge")` try this

Comment: Remember in R, the data to be plotted on one axis should be in one column only.  This is unlike MS excel where data on two columns can be plotted on one axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ggplot2:

Say `df` is the name of your data frame, first you need to transform it to long format with `pivot_longer()` from the `tidyr` package:

```
df <- tidyr::pivot_longer(df, cols=-1)
```

Obs: The `-1` wont transform the first row into long. Then it should look something like this (sorry for bad quality):

[image]

So we want the `name` column in the x axis (one bar for each value in it), `value` in y, and each bar should be divided in colors by `status`, so we pass it to `fill`:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x=name, y=value, fill=status) + geom_col()
```